# How to call the library in hooks folder using codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a problem I tried this codes:

- enabled hooks in application/config/config.php

  ```
  $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
  ```

---

- added library in applciation/config/autoload.php

  ```
  $autoload['libraries'] = array('smarty','session');
  ```

---

- code in application/config/hooks.php:

  ```
  $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
      'class'    => 'App_auth',
      'function' => 'index',
      'filename' => 'App_auth.php',
      'filepath' => 'controllers',
      'params'   => ''
  );
  ```

---

- code in application/controller/App_auth.php :

  ```
  class Auth_module
  {
      private $CI;

      function Auth_module()
      {
          $this->CI = &get_instance();
      }

      function index()
      {
          echo'aaaaaaaa';exit(0);
          if ($this->CI->session->userdata('user_id') == "" )  // If no session found redirect to login page.
          {
              redirect(site_url('login'));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

---

- sample code in application/libraries/Session.php:

  ```
  Please check this site for the codehttp://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html
  ```

---

- Replaced function userdata($item) with this code:

  ```
  function userdata($item)
  {
      echo'bbbb';exit;
      return ( ! isset($this->userdata[$item])) ? FALSE : $this->userdata[$item];
  }
  ```

---

I don't have any idea what could be the solution as I already other codes. Please enlighten me with this. THANKS! :)

Why is that echo'aaaa'; and echo 'bbbb'; are not showing?
Also is there wrong with my code?

Comment: check instance private $CI;

Comment: updated the App_auth.php

Comment: no the issue now is that I can't display the echo'aaa';exit; in the library I used

Comment: For login matter, you should use precontroller hook. You want to check user before he touch sensitive location.

Comment: @tpojka yup even if I use pre_controller still the same result... :(

Answer (score 0):

enable hooks in config

```
$config[‘enable_hooks’] = TRUE;
```

[Codeigniter Hooks tutorials](https://qasimbadami.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/codeigniter-hooks-tutorial/)

---

Your `Auth_module` should contain

```
function Auth_module()
{
$this->CI = &get_instance();
}
```

Comment: `Line Number: 8` where is it ??

Comment: And where did you download the file ?? add link as well

Comment: Hi I updated the App_auth.php up there. Now I go to system\libraries\Session.php and find the function userdata($item) and add echo'aaaa';exit; but i the echo did not appear

Comment: and the error now is gone but i'm not sure if the library is called because the echo exit didn't work

Comment: load session with autoload in config

Comment: the link you said here was my reference -> Codeigniter Hooks tutorials

Comment: did you placed the library in controller ??

Comment: is this correct? $autoload['libraries'] = array('smarty','session');

Comment: I place it here -> system\libraries\Session.php

Comment: where did you download the libraray. give me ink

Comment: I already created this: $config['encryption_key'] = 'qwerty'; but the echo exit still didn't appear.

Comment: @BrylleLagunda no i mean your app_auth libraray

Comment: here -> https://qasimbadami.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/codeigniter-hooks-tutorial/

I updated it base on the link you gave to me

Comment: app auth is placed in `application/controller`

Comment: Still the same (echo exit didn't show up and no error) I move the App_auth.php from application\hooks (folder) to application\controllers (folder)

Comment: is there any controller call  `login`. And whats the error passing now??

Comment: none. There is no "login" found under this folder "application\controllers".
there are only welocme.php, App_auth and index.html in that folder

Comment: so make it valid controller name

Comment: hmm I'm getting confused... I'll update my code above.

Comment: alright updated the file in config/hooks.php
updated the file in controller/App_auth.php, added echo exit; and this did not display